# Still prompted for a password after adding SSH public key to a server

Tags: webserver, authentication

I'm attempting to setup a git repository on my Dreamhost web server by following the "Setup: For the Impatient" instructions [here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Git). I'm having difficulty setting up public key access to the server.

After successfully creating my public key, I ran the following command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/[MY KEY].pub | ssh [USER]@[MACHINE] "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

...replacing the appropriate placeholders with the correct values.

Everything seemed to go through fine. The server asked for my password, and, as far as I can tell, executed the command. There is indeed a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server.

The problem: When I try to SSH into the server, it still asks for my password. My understanding is that it shouldn't be asking for my password anymore. What am I missing?

EDIT: SSH -v Log:

```
Macbook:~ michaeleckert$ ssh -v [USER]@[SERVER URL]
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [SERVER URL] [[SERVER IP]] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA [STRING OF NUMBERS AND LETTERS SEPARATED BY SEMI-COLONS]
debug1: Host ‘[SERVER URL]' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/michaeleckert/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
[USER]@[SERVER URL]'s password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to [SERVER URL] ([[SERVER IP]]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8

 Welcome to [SERVER URL]

Any malicious and/or unauthorized activity is strictly forbidden.
All activity may be logged by DreamHost Web Hosting.

Last login: Sun Nov  3 12:04:21 2013 from [MY IP]
[[SERVER NAME]]$
```

Comment: You might be seeing a password prompt for your key and not for the SSH connection. Did you password protect your key when you created it? If so, your local machine – not the server – will ask you for a password ("Enter passphrase **for key**") when you try to connect to a server using that key. You can only use passwordless SSH logins for keys without a password. (i.e. When creating your key, don't password-protect it. This is less secure, but more convenient – it depends if security or convenience is more important to you.)

Comment: I didn't password protect my key. I was under the impression that a passwordless-key would work better setting up my server with Git. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: You should get password-less login if the key file is unprotected. I've added some things to check below.

Comment: Looking at the ssh -v log I just added, it seems to have tried "id_rsa" and "id_dsa" before giving up. Why is it trying these file names? Should I name my public key one of these names?

Comment: Turns out I should. See the comments below my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was very simple: rename my two public key files to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. I have no idea why this is what they have to be called. Please feel free to edit this answer to make it more informative.

Comment: Aha! SSH2 expects key files to be named id_rsa or id_dsa. It will not look for other files unless you explicitly pass the path to the key file with the `-file` flag. So, if you renamed your key files after creating them or called them something different to begin with, that would explain why you couldn't use key-based authentication. Well done for solving it. You should mark this answer as the correct one so others know your question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

On Client side:

- open configuration file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`;
- here look for `PreferredAuthentications`;
- make sure `password` comes after `publickey` and not viceversa

---

In my case `password` was written before `publickey`, so ssh would prompt me for password even though I had copied my pub_key onto server.

This problem can be found out easily using verbose:

`ssh -v compute@compute1
...
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password`

As you can see `password` is chosen before trying to use publickey.

Edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by moving `password` after `publickey`

> PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,`publickey,password`,hostbased,gssapi-with-mi

Now you can login without being prompt for pwd.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

#### On the server:

1. Change the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file permissions using:
   `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. Change the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file owner using:
   `` chown `whoami` ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ``
3. Check that the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is not empty:
   (`cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should display some output)

(Steps one and two are recommended in the [OpenSSH FAQ](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14).)

#### On the client

1. Are you logging in with the same user account as the one you added the key for on the server? (i.e. Is the user in the `ssh USER@ip` command you're using to connect the same as the USER in the command you copied the file to the server with?)
2. Connect using SSH verbose mode (`ssh -v user@ip`) and edit your question to add the output (with any IP addresses, usernames and hostnames masked).

Comment: I tried server 1 and 3 with no luck yet. Regarding 2: Would this be the same username I'm attempting to login with? Also, what character is that username surrounded with? Client 1: I believe I'm using the same user. 2: I'm going to try that now. PS: +1 for the very actionable answer!

Comment: SSH -v log added to OP.